# What are the consequences, positive or negative, to having a surrogate primary key for a table which already has a guaranteed unique column?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, primary-key, surrogate-key

I recently made a table that looks like the one below

```
CREATE TABLE example(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  subindusty_id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
  -- other fields...
)
```

I realized that in this table I could just remove the column called `id` and make `subindustry_id` the primary key.

Thinking back, the only reason I can think of for why I didn't make `subindustry_id` the primary key is for the sake of consistency, considering that I have a lot of other tables with a column called `id`.

Except for things like consistency*, are there any tangible benefits/downsides to having this additional id column as the primary key when there's already another column that'd be a good primary key?

*Consistency as in "that's the way the rest of the tables look". The kind where you're enforcing a certain type of style. I guess the point of this question is to question the practice of giving every single table an `id` column regardless of the fact that they might already have a more suitable candidate for a primary key.

Comment: There are a lot of questions here about it: http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=surrogate+key and in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=surrogate+key

Comment: I appreciate the links, but from what I've seen they don't answer my question. Either it's some debate about 3NF or they assume that the `natural key` will change. Regarding 3NF, I don't care about that for this question, and regarding the uniqueness of the natural key, I have a `UNIQUE` constraint on it because I'm sure that it'll never change.

Comment: @AR7 it seems as if you know a lot about this subject and you're asking us to repeat it because you're unsatisfied with what you know. Well we to know what you're looking for then. You don't just get to ask a vague question that requires brain dumps from everyone. Well, we'd rather you not anyway. That said it's a very frequent thing not to have a surrogate key. I do it all the time. Literally.. Every. Project. That said, lots of my tables have surrogate keys too.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I've never thought about it as "it seems as if you know a lot about this subject and you're asking us to repeat it because you're unsatisfied with what you know" before, and you're 100% right. I know the theory, but I have no experience so I'm trying to crutch on the dba community for that. I guess I have to figure it out for myself. Thanks :)

Comment: For this particular example the `id` column is useless and can be removed without any problems. It adds no value and just increases the space used by the table and adds the burden of a second index that needs to be maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree a lot with comments from @MDCCL:

> You should analyze each particular case —that is, every particular table within its whole context, that is, the entire database structure— to define if it requires the appending of a system-generated surrogate column, as such an artifact is an additional aspect that requires its particular administration. Consistency with the way the rest of the tables look is irrelevant, from the logical and physical points of view

A few pointers from my side (the ones that come to my mind at the moment, and that probably are not all there is to it)

**Negative consequences:**

1. You need more space for everything: each row is wider, and you have an extra index to maintain. Every write will take (a little bit) more time, and so will every read, because you use more space to read and write the same *real* information. Let's say you have a log of the readings of several thermometers, one per second. You have one table `thermometers (thermometer_id PK, ...etc...)` and one `readings (thermometer_id, reading_timestamp, value_read)`. Your readings table has a *natural key*: `(thermometer_id, reading_timestamp)`, because you cannot have two different readings at the same time. I would normally make this my PK, and forget about surrogates.
2. Using surrogate keys tend to obscure the real structure and meaning of your data. For instance, imagine you have a tables `persons`,  `books` and `books_liked_by_persons`. This last table is a `m x n` table, and most of the times contains only `(person_id, book_id)` pairs. Adding a third `id` is in such cases most probably meaningless and noisy.

**Positive consequences:**

1. In some very specific cases, you may want to have different tables with share one part of their structure (let's say, for instance, you want some of them to have always a `country_code`, and `xxx_id`) so that some application is easier to develop because the same pattern can be used to process different tables. [This tends to be rather uncommon, AFAIK, but is also possible.]
2. Using a surrogate key, even if there are some other *alternative keys* might help you save *space* (and probably, *time*). Imagine your *natural key* is a *PGP key* (note 1). It takes a `char(800)` (approx.) to store it. Imagine you have several tables that reference this one. It will save (a lot of) space all around to have a *surrogate integer key* (8 or 16 bytes) on the original table, because the *referencing tables* will store 8 (or 16) bytes instead of 800. The accounting needs to be done for each specific case.
3. If you ever have to edit your data "by hand" (and, some day, you probably will), you don't want to look for keys which are really long. You prefer surrogates in that case.
4. *Some* databases (not PostgreSQL, at least as of now) will *cluster* the data of your tables using your primary key as a clustering index (or can do it by default unless you explicitly state the contrary). In such cases, it is normally advisable to have an always incrementing primary key; to avoid fragmentation.

So: every case needs analyzing, weighting and deciding. Sometimes *consistency* may be confused by *flying on autopilot*.

---

Side note: There are several different *naming conventions*. I prefer the one where `id` is never used, and a `persons` table has a `person_id` column if needed.

Note 1: A PGP key looks more or less like:

`mQENBFiBGbcBCADBAe1p70ZPGwM6gmAAFTd13gv68rOUQEqlhddjkJZoiKs8SJuX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=RYbd`

Comment: never use `id` it should be a cardinal sin.

Comment: For the example in the question the `id` column is useless. It adds no value and doesn't save space because it's an int just like the natural primary key.